# Regarding spectral radius

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras, norms, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a $C^*$ algebra. Let $a\in A$ be such that $a^*a-aa^*\geq 0$. Doe this imply that the spectral radius of $a$ is equal to $\|a\|$?

Comment: It may help, in looking for proofs or counter-examples, to know that if we realise $A$ as a unital star-subalgebra of $B(H)$, then the condition on $a$ is the definition of being a _hyponormal operator_

Comment: yes. I know for a Hyponormal operator $r(T)=\|T\|$. I am not able to prov e it for C* algebra case.

Comment: Why not? If you take any unital embedding $A \to B(H)$ then this embedding preserves norm (by definition) and preserves spectral radius. In any case, why not look at the proof for the case of hyponormal operators and modify it if necessary?

Comment: Actually, my approach was that since $a^*a-aa^*\geq 0$, then $\|a^*a\|\geq\|aa^*\|$, Then using Corollary 15.6 in Complete normed algebras by Bonsal and Duncan, $a^*a=aa^*$. But that will mean that every Hyponormal operator is normal in the case of B(H). Can you tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: In a $C^*$ algebra you always have $ \Vert a a^* \Vert = \Vert a^* a \Vert$ for any $a $. I can't go check what this corollary 15.6 is, but you are probably misusing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, see T. Ando, On hyponormal operators, *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.* **14** (1963), 290-291. His main result states that $\|T^n\| = \|T\|^n$ for any hyponormal operator, which implies the conclusion by Gelfand's spectral radius formula.